# Ax 2012 Dialog box help text

Tags: axapta

I have a question on dialog boxes in ax 2012, For BOX::yesNO type dialog is it possible to give help text to 'Yes' button and 'NO' button, if possible please let me know.

when i place the cursor on any of the buttons, help text  given by me must be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customize the help text of the buttons in the `Box::yesNo()` dialog form.

You can create and use a custom dialog class or a form.

Comment: Yes, instead of creating a new custom form, existing form `SysBoxForm` can be customized to your advantage.